# use a drop down list to copy paste values from a table.

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a drop down list called Ted_ID that contains ID's 
I want to write vba code that says if a user selects an ID from the drop down then it will look into the table and find the corresponding Ted ID and copy paste the corresponding value (corptax entity name) to the right of it into lets say column G.

[table and drop down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaP1B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I would like to suggest you the following VBA code will help you to Insert ID of your choice in the INPUTBOX and then search it into the Data Range, and Copy it to Paste after few Rows.*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim FirstAddress As String, cF As Range,RowsToCopy As String

ActiveSheet.Cells(186, 1).Activate

With ActiveSheet.Columns(1)

    Set cF = .Find(What:=InputBox("Enter ID Number", "Search ID"), _
                After:=ActiveCell, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)


     If Not cF Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = cF.Address

        Do
               cF.EntireRow.Copy
               Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
               Set cF = .FindNext(cF)


            Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address = FirstAddress

    End If
End With

End Sub
```

**NB: Remember my Data Range is A186 to D195. You need to alter the following values in VBA Code according to your Data Range.**

1. Find 186 in 3rd line, (its **ROW Number A186**), replace this Row Nu with Your's.
2. Find in 4th line .Column(1), **it represents Column A**, Change it as per your Start Column Value.
3. Check line 17th & replace Sheet Name if required also, Range("A",, replace it with yours Data Range start Column name.
4. In place of Dropdown I've used INPUTBOX, if you feel replace it.

**Note,** *I've tested this code before post it here as Solution.*

*I do believe you find this code useful.*

Comment: @Clarisa,, Nice to hear from you,,, since you found it as your expectations then,,, vote my solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider a non-VBA solution?

You need a list of TED ID's for your dropdown, and you have a list of the Entity Names, so you can use those as a lookup table with VLOOKUP().  The formula in F3 of the screenshot below is:

`=VLOOKUP(D3,A2:B6,2)`

[image]